# Python: Pandas Dataframe select row by given index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a pandas dataframe of this kind:

```
data = {'Index':[1a,2a,3a,4a], 'col1':[20.1,20.2,20.3,20.4], 'col2': [30.2,30.5,30.7,30.5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df1.set_index('Index')
print(df1)
```

output:

```
        col1  col2
Index            
1a      20.1  30.2
2a      20.2  30.5
3a      20.3  30.7
4a      20.4  30.5
```

Now my aim is to select the row with a specific index, say 2a, so the output should be:

```
        col1  col2
Index            
2a      20.2  30.5
```

I tried it with following command (see e.g. [this](https://www.interviewqs.com/ddi-code-snippets/rows-cols-python) tutorial):

```
df1.loc[df1['Index'] == 2]
```

but for some reason it does not work, why?

Comment: just use `loc`? `df1.loc[['2a']]`?

Comment: If you want the row with index 18, which can have any other location in the df, just do df.iloc[df.index == 18]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.loc`:

```
>>> df.loc['2a']
col1    20.2
col2    30.5
Name: 2a, dtype: float64

>>> df.loc['2a', 'col1']
20.2
```